# TRane furnace error code 3 blinks

Tags: hvac

Fan runs continuously no heat 3 blinks error code 
So I've learnt it seems a draft problem .....
Blew through little hose and clear disconnected exhaust and still nothing any ideas  thanks dave

Comment: What model of furnace is this?

Comment: For some reason the draft inducer is not getting the system to the proper pressure, or the pressure switch is malfunctioning.  Is this a newly installed system, or a system that's been in service for years? Have you checked to make sure the intake and exhaust are both unclogged and unrestricted?

Answer (score -1):

replace pressure switch it is a possibility that it is bad

Comment: A little more information would be helpful, something like to verify if the switch is bad remove the connections to the switch and use a ohm meter to verify if the switch is changing states when the fan is on / off. would make this a better answer.